# Using $.contains to find if an element contains another with focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery, which is part of the handling for double-clicking a table row. If the row contains an input box with active focus I want to exit the function, otherwise I want to proceed:

```
$("#foo tbody tr").dblclick(function() {
        if ($.contains( $(this)[0], document.activeElement)) {
            return;
        }
        // otherwise, do something with the row
    });
```

However, it's not working: the conditional apparently always returns `false` (the activeElement not in the double-clicked row), even when the row does contain an input box with focus.

What's wrong?

EDIT: what I'm doing here is moving the row from one table to another when it is double-clicked. But each row contains a cell which contains text that can be clicked on to edit it (when the user clicks once on the cell text, it becomes an input box). What I find is that if the user is editing this cell but double clicks on the row, the move happens, which I want to avoid.

Comment: FWIW `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: If you double click the `tr` element, then the `input` can no longer have focus...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unless you double click the `input`, in which case the event will bubble -- which works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/uq0ga86v/

Comment: @George right, but then if you're expecting people to double click on the `input`, why not just put the event handler on the `input` itself and avoid the check for `document.activeElement`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's a very good question (: -- OP?

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my question to give more details.

Comment: As Rory already pointed out, as soon as you double click your row, your input is going to lose focus; your `if` statement will never be true.

Comment: Ah... OK: you're right. It's not active, but it is still an input box, and that's where things are going wrong for me. But when it loses focus, for some reason the `blur()` function I've attached to it isn't being called. If there's no simple answer, I'll ask a new question...

Comment: Are you saying the `.dblclick()` event is triggered before the `.blur()`? Hence the input box is never switched back?

Comment: the `blur` event is raised before the `dblclick` is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the element with focus and check for that in your doubleclick event. You can then remove the class whenever it's needed.http://jsfiddle.net/uq0ga86v/5/

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $('input').removeClass('focus');
    $(this).addClass('focus');
})
$("#foo tbody tr").dblclick(function() {    
        if ($(this).find('input.focus').length != 0) {
            alert('g');
        }
        // otherwise, do something with the row
       $(this).find('input.focus').removeClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better handle the double click directly on the expected input, doing on a row will raise the **blur event** on any active element inside the row.

FYI, you can delegate that event to the row *(see: [Direct and delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events))*

```
$("#foo tbody tr")
  .off(".nsActive")
  .on("dblclick.nsActive", ".expected-input", function (e) {
     //code here
  });
```

Keep in mind that in this case we employed the event delegation to `"#foo tbody tr"` meaning that element must exist before delegating the `dblclick` event on `".expected-input"` to it.

See **jQuery.on**: [Event names and namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) and [Direct and delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).